spring security with <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" /> but still go to access-denied-handler
I intentionally set the http tag in my applicationContext-security.xml to permit all request url as follow:
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">     
        </global-method-security> 
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">        
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />      
            <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="webSEALFilter" />
            <custom-filter after="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="myFilter"/>     
            <access-denied-handler error-page="/error/abc"/>
            <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/logout"/>  
            <session-management invalid-session-url="${${ENV}.login.url}">
                <concurrency-control expired-url="${${ENV}.login.url}" />
            </session-management>
        </http>
        
<beans:bean id="webSecurityExpressionHandler" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
        

but still for ANY request like
http://localhost:8080/SLIS/message/getNonExpiredMessage/0/1
http://localhost:8080/SLIS/adminAnnouncement

it still go to access-denied-handler as found in console message

[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-3) No mapping for POST >/SLIS/error/abc
[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (default task-3) No endpoint POST /SLIS/error/abc.

why?
I use spring security 6.2.4
--------------------------- Edit -------------------------------------
With unknown reason, but if I add
<csrf disabled="true"/>

inside <http> tag, the problem is disappeared, don't know the exact reason yet.

Yes, it is due to csrf setting. As in Spring documentation
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html

Spring Security’s CSRF protection will produce an HTTP 403 access
denied. This can be customized by configuring the AccessDeniedHandler
to process InvalidCsrfTokenException differently.
As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with
XML configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF protection, the
corresponding XML configuration can be seen below.
 

